# AWS ADFS does not redirect back to Kibana after authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, amazon-cognito, saml, adfs

I'm trying to setup login in AWS ElasticSearch Kibana via Simple AD (from AWS Directory Services) with Cognito User Pools.
I have:

- Simple AD, using for AWS VPN connections
- ES with Kibana
- Cognito User Pool, configured to access to Kibana with Google Identity Provider.

So I'm tying to add SAML identity provider to that user pool, so I can use existing AD users to login to Kibana.

I've setup ADFS authentication in Kibana with Cognito user pool.
Completely went through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373090/5938853)
While testing, If I enter wrong AD user\password, it says me wrong password, ok.
But if I enter a valid AD login and password nothing happens, there are just blank fields for login and password.
What can be wrong with setup, why it does not redirect back to Kibana after authentification?